# Matrix 8x5 problems can't solve

Tags: matrix, implementation, calculated-columns

**i am just learning Matrix and algorithm. i stack on one question that i couldn't solve yet. Question is,**

matrix composed of integer values

```
#[0 0 0 2 2]
#|1 1 7 2 2|
#|2 2 7 2 1|
#|2 1 7 4 4|
#|2 7 7 4 4|
#|4 6 6 0 4|
#|4 4 6 4 4|
#[4 4 6 4 4]
```

**An area is defined when several identical value are connected together (either horizontally or vertically) For example with the above matrix, we can find the following areas**

```
#[0 0 0 * *]
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#[* * * * *]

#[* * * 2 2]
#|* * * 2 2|
#|* * * 2 *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#[* * * * *]

#[* * * * *]
#|1 1 * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#[* * * * *]
```

**The problem consists in implementing the function "Find Count Element Of Biggest Area" which find the biggest area (the area composed with the biggest number of elements), and return the number of elements from this area. For example with the above matrix, the biggest area is:**

```
#[* * * * *]
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * * *|
#|* * * 4 4|
#|* * * 4 4|
#|* * * * 4|
#|* * * 4 4|
#[* * * 4 4]
```

**And so the function would return 9 (the area is composed of 9 elements).**

Any help please about this question how do i solve ? best way ?

Thanks..

Comment: Actually  i have to implement the function and would be return 9 (the area is composed of 9 elements)

Comment: Please some example for explain below questions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I couldn't resist to do your homework ...

The following C# code uses a recursive function to count all non-visited neighbours of a given matrix cell. The main program loops through all rows and columns to find the cell with the highest number of neighbours with identical content.

```
namespace akArrayCluster
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] a = new int[,] 
            {
                {0, 0, 0, 2, 2},
                {1, 1, 7, 2, 2},
                {2, 2, 7, 2, 1},
                {2, 1, 7, 4, 4},
                {2, 7, 7, 4, 4},
                {4, 6, 6, 0, 4},
                {4, 4, 6, 4, 4},
                {4, 4, 6, 4, 4}
            };
            int row;
            int col;
            int res = getBiggestArea(a, out row, out col);

            o("");
            o("Biggest area has " + res + " cells");
            o("Top-left cell is [" + row + ";" + col + "]");
        }

        static int getBiggestArea(int[,] a, out int row, out int col)
        {
            int opt = 0;
            int cnt;
            int rows = a.GetLength(0);
            int cols = a.GetLength(1);
            bool[,] visited = new bool[rows, cols];

            row = col = -1;

            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                {
                    setAllToFalse(visited, rows, cols);

                    cnt = getNeighbourCount(a[r, c], a, visited, r, c);
                    if (cnt > opt)
                    {
                        opt = cnt;
                        row = r;
                        col = c;
                    }
                }

            setAllToFalse(visited, rows, cols);   //  edited col --> cols
            getNeighbourCount(a[row, col], a, visited, row, col);
            showSolution(a, visited, rows, cols);

            return opt;
        }

        static void setAllToFalse(bool[,] v, int rows, int cols)
        {            
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                    v[row, col] = false;
        }

        static void showSolution(int[,] a, bool[,] visited, int rows, int cols)
        {
            string s;

            o("");
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            {
                s = "";
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
                    s += " " + (visited[row, col] ? a[row, col].ToString() : ".");
                }

                o(s);
            }
        }

        static int getNeighbourCount(int ca, int[,] a, bool[,] visited, 
                                     int row, int col)
        {
            int nc = 0;
            int rows = a.GetLength(0);
            int cols = a.GetLength(1);

            if ((row >= 0) && (row < rows) && 
                (col >= 0) && (col < cols) && 
                (ca == a[row, col]) && !visited[row, col])
            {
                visited[row, col] = true;

                nc = 1
                    + getNeighbourCount(ca, a, visited, row, col - 1)
                    + getNeighbourCount(ca, a, visited, row - 1, col)
                    + getNeighbourCount(ca, a, visited, row, col + 1)
                    + getNeighbourCount(ca, a, visited, row + 1, col);
            }

            return nc;
        }

        static void o(string s)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The result running the program:

```
 . . . . .
 . . . . .
 . . . . .
 . . . 4 4
 . . . 4 4
 . . . . 4
 . . . 4 4
 . . . 4 4

Biggest area has 9 cells
Top-left cell is [3;3]
```

Second example (cf comment below):

```
 . 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2
 . . . 2 2
 . . . . 2

Biggest area has 12 cells
Top-left cell is [0;1]
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Mr. Axel  this is very good example for me so i will study with this.

Comment: Oww sorry i didnt see it :)

Comment: And how about the number of elements of the biggest rectangular areas , Mr. Axel ?  which area i have to change on function ? Thanks again.

Comment: for example this matrix, `[0 2 2 2 2]
|2 2 2 2 2|
|4 5 6 2 2|
|0 9 8 7 2|`

Comment: There was a bug in the call to setAllToFalse(). I've fixed it in the original post. The result is 12. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Oww yeah i see and i changed it  col to cols  thanks. oww no my second question is i have to found biggest rectangular area in matrix now :) So the algorithm should return 8 (the number of elements of the biggest rectangular areas)

Comment: in `[0 2 2 2 2] |2 2 2 2 2| |4 5 6 2 2| |0 9 8 7 2|`

Comment: ok. A good opportunitiy for you to show what you've learned from the first problem ;-)

Comment: I have tryed code at above , but i get result is 22 not 8 and i cant show rows and columns like you did. this is more complex algorithm. please can you check Mr. Axel. thanks.

Comment: To get the biggest rectangle: Scan the rows and columns like in my solution. For every (row;colum) scan width=1,2,...max and for every width scan height=1,2...max. So, you can find the biggest rectangle without recursion. It is just a search in four nested loops.